# How to display images in SharePoint 2013 Calculated Column in List- help with syntax please

Tags: calculated-column, image-display, sharepoint-list

I need to display images in a SharePoint 2013 list based on the following criteria:

If 'Member' Column = yes then display Green tick icon (URL listed below)

If 'Member' Column = no then display red cross icon (URL listed below)

I need some assistance with my Formula based on the first criteria only and it keeps producing errors:

```
="<DIV><imgsrc='"&IF[Member]="Yes","http://isourcedev.walfs.local/sites/wfin/SiteAssets/Tick%20Green%20Circle.png"))&"'></DIV>"
```

I would appreciate some help with the syntax as I am very new to this and think its to do with lack of brackets etc.Thanks in Advance.

SharePoint user.

Comment: Can someone clarify where to put this code please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can try this code to achieve your functionality:

```
="<div><img style='float: left' src='http://isourcedev.walfs.local/sites/wfin/SiteAssets/"
&IF(Member="Yes"
;"Tick%20Green%20Circle.png"
;IF(Member="No"
;"Tick%20Red%20Circle.png"
)
)
&"'></div>"
```

Source: [Images in calculated columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151635/images-in-calculated-columns)

Also you can try this code if your choice is restricted to Yes/No :

```
="<DIV><img src='http://isourcedev.walfs.local/sites/wfin/SiteAssets/"&IF([Completed?], "Tick%20Green%20Circle.png", "Tick%20Red%20Circle.png")&"'></DIV>"
```

Source: [Using a Calculated Column to show Images](http://www.dreamsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-simple-kpi-using-calculated-columns/)

If You need empty for Member = No

```
=IF([Member?], "<DIV><img src='http://isourcedev.walfs.local/sites/wfin/SiteAssets/Tick%20Green%20Circle.png/><DIV>", "")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I realised just before I read your post that I needed a space between img src which solved the issue for me so thankyou for confirming this. But I need to add another criteria to the formula to say if 'Member' = no, then blank (we don't want an image in there). How do you add blank to the formula?

Comment: Have added formula for Member=No in my answer..

Comment: Hi. Thank you - you have been very helpful so far. I need some further assistance please on how to combine the two criteria (Yes = image and No = blank or no image into the one formula). So far I have this formula for yes (which works) so can you please complete the formula for me with both criteria added in there:

Comment: ="<DIV><img width='24px' height='24px' src='"&IF(Member="Yes","http://isourcedev.walfs.local/sites/wfin/SiteAssets/Tick%20Green%20Circle.png")&"'></DIV>"

Comment: And I also want to centre the symbol (image). Is that just: style='float: centre'